# Is there any API for Google Map Maker for .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to develop an app that can add, Edit and Update details of a place using Google Map Maker using WPF. But I can not find any API for Google Map Maker in Google.

Can any one tell me how can I achieve Add, Edit and Update functionality of Google Map Maker?

Thank`s in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no public API for Google Map Maker yet. It is accessible only for large companies such as EasyWay. And it won't become public soon, the development of Google Map Maker goes slowly.

Comment: UPD 2017 Mar: Google shut down MapMaker: https://support.google.com/mapmaker/answer/7195127?hl=en